# Python: Pair alphabets after loop is completed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to pair Alphabets by this

```
import string
a=string.uppercase
for i in range(0,30):
    print a[i%26]*(i / 26+1)

This will print A-Z and then after Z it will print AA BB like string
```

but i need to put this string like `AA AB AC AD AE` until the range is defined after printing A-Z then the result will be like 
print A-Z then AA AB AC ....

Comment: So is what you are asking for is a list the same as Excel uses for its column naming?  After AZ, should BA be printed, or should it stop at 52 words?

Comment: you are correct i am writing this function to put data in excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `itertools` module and use a generator to handle this pretty cleanly:

```
from itertools import count, product, islice
from string import ascii_uppercase

def multiletters(seq):
    for n in count(1):
        for s in product(seq, repeat=n):
            yield ''.join(s)
```

gives

```
>>> list(islice(multiletters('ABC'), 20))
['A', 'B', 'C', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ACA', 'ACB']
>>> list(islice(multiletters(ascii_uppercase), 30))
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD']
```

and you can make an object and get them one by one, if you'd prefer:

```
>>> m = multiletters(ascii_uppercase)
>>> next(m)
'A'
>>> next(m)
'B'
>>> next(m)
'C'
```

[Update: I should note though that I pass data between Python and Excel all the time -- am about to do so, actually -- and never need this function.  But if you have a specific question about the best way to exchange data, it's probably better to ask a separate question than to edit this one now that there are several answers to the current question.]

Comment: Can i ask that how you pass the data to Excel from Python,I am quite interested

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a nested for loop, like this:

```
import string

def get_string(val):
    return string.uppercase[val%26]*(val / 26+1)


for i in range(0,26):
    for j in range(0, 26):
        print get_string(i) + get_string(j)
```

Note that I defined your indexing of `string.uppercase` to a function (`get_string`) so that its code would not be repeated.

Comment: I have edited my question.Actually A-z needs to be printed first and then the rest of the range is printed as AA AB AC

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this

```
import string

def get_string(val):
    return string.uppercase[val%26]*(val / 26+1)


for i in range(-1,26):
    for j in range(0, 26):
        if i==-1:
            print get_string(j)
        else:
            print get_string(i) + get_string(j)
```

The first time through the outer loop, do not print a leading character (the first 26 Excel columns) then after that the next 26 columns print a letter followed by a second letter.

Working example available on ideone.com -> http://ideone.com/M862Ra