# All strings with list of characters?

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm making a specialized utility similar to John the Ripper, and I'd like to use a loop that returns all strings up to x characters that can be formed from the string. For example, if the "seed" string is `abcd`, it should return:

```
a
b
c
d
aa
ab
ac
```

and so on. If the character limit is 10, it would generate `aaaaaaaaaa`, `abcddcbaaa`, and so on. Is there a simple `for` loop to do this, or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: You are looking for [`itertools.permutations()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: Is this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381940/python-pair-alphabets-after-loop-is-completed/14382997#14382997) the sort of thing you have in mind?  [It'd be easily modified to add a size limit.]

Comment: @Lattyware man, Python is *awesome*.

Comment: @Lattyware: `itertools.product()`, no? Permutations don't include repeated values, so no `'aaaaaaaa'`.

Comment: @Lattyware I thought permutation meant the same characters in any order. e.g, `abc` has one permutation: `abc`, but `abc` has many combinations: `abc`, `acb`, `cba`, etc. I also thought permutations and combinations include all characters, so `a` is neither a permutation of combination of `abc`

Comment: @tkbx: You got those two backwards. `abc` has only one combination of 3 (`abc`) but six permutations of 3. (`abc` does, however, have 3 combinations of 2 and 3 combinations of 1, one of which is indeed `a`).

Comment: @DavidRobinson so is "a" a permutation of "abc"?

Comment: Only in the sense that it's a possible nPr, where n=3 and r=1, though it's a fairly trivial example.

Comment: @Wooble Indeed, mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll self-plagiarize from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381940/python-pair-alphabets-after-loop-is-completed/14382997#14382997) and add a maximum length:

```
from itertools import product

def multiletters(seq, max_length):
    for n in range(1, max_length+1):
        for s in product(seq, repeat=n):
            yield ''.join(s)
```

which gives

```
>>> list(multiletters("abc", 2))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']
>>> list(multiletters("abcd", 4))[:8]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad']
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment's use `itertools.premutations` or even better take a look @DSM's answer, as this one misses the doubles:

```
In [194]: from itertools import chain, permutations

In [195]: s = 'abcd'

In [196]: map(''.join,chain.from_iterable(permutations(s,x) 
                               for x in range(1,len(s)+1)))
Out[196]: 
['a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'ab',
 'ac',
 'ad',
 'ba',
 'bc',
 'bd',
  ...
 'dbca',
 'dcab',
 'dcba']
```

Anyway,  here's a version of @DSM's answer that returns a list:

```
from itertools import product

def ms(seq, max_length):
    return [''.join(s) for n in range(1, max_length+1)
                       for s in product(seq,repeat=n)]
```

Comment: This won't give `aa`, though.

Comment: @DMS -- Arhhh. I guess, `product` it is then :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def all_strings(alphabet, length_limit=None):
  n_letters = len(alphabet)
  length = 0
  n_strings = 1
  buf = []
  while True:
    for i in xrange(0, n_strings):
      k = i
      for j in xrange(length - 1, -1, -1):
        buf[j] = alphabet[k % n_letters]
        k /= n_letters
      yield ''.join(buf)
    length += 1
    if length == length_limit:
      break
    n_strings *= n_letters
    buf.append(alphabet[0])

for s in all_strings('abcd', length_limit=4):
  print s
```

Answer (score 1):

Use itertools.permuataions.

```
for i in range(2,4):
    tuples = itertools.permutations('abca' , i)
    print( list(tuples))
```

The example code sequence generates:

[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')]

[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b')]