# Python Iterating through A to ZZZZ

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to iterate in this manner:

```
a, b, c, d, ....z,   
aa, ab, ac, ad, ..., az,   
ba, bb, bc, bd, ...bz, ...zz,   
aaa, aab, ...., zzzz
```

This seems to be trickier than i thought it would be.

Cant get my head around it.

whats the best way to perform permutation on `'a'` to `'zzzz'`

1. I suppose I should do while loop instead of for loop since I'm not sure about the number of loops I have to perform but rather know what's the starting point ('a') and the end point('zzzz')?
2. maybe have a function that returns the next item to loop? If so, what would be the rule for getting the next permutation? Then, I can just check for the next item to be 'zzzz' and if it isnt, continue.

hmm anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is this the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694006/all-strings-with-list-of-characters)?

Comment: @DSM ohhh never knew such module exists. seems like a possibility, let me play around with it. Thank you!

Comment: So far people have given you answers involving `permutations` and `combinations_with_replacement`.  Eventually they'll evolve to `product` and they'll recover a version of my old answer. :^)

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools
import string

strings = [''.join(letters)
           for length in xrange(1, 5)
           for letters in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase,
                                            repeat=length)]
```

This goes over every length from 1 to 4, and for each length, takes the Cartesian product of `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` with itself that many times.

Comment: It's better to use `string.ascii_lowercase`, as it's present in both Python2 & 3.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor: Yeah, we probably don't want this to be locale-dependent, too.